# I'm trying to find the complexity of the following algorithm:

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm trying to find the complexity of the following algorithm:

```
count = 1
j=0
for i = 1 to 100 do
        count += i
for k = 1 to n do
        count *= k
while j < n do
        count +=j
        j *= 2;
end while
```

Comment: For first loop which has constant number of 100, it has 100 complexity, for second loop it has n times. In While loop, because you didn't show initial value of j, I can't say complexity of it. So, up to this level, algorithm has O(100+n)

Answer (score 0):

For the first for loop time complexity is constant *O(100)*.
The second for loop has *O(n)* time complexity.
The while loop also has *O(n)* time complexity.
So total time complexity is *O(100+n+n) = O(n)*